# HttpGet with three relational tables with dot net core web api

Tags: .net-core, relational-database, http-get

I have tree tables Sectors , Centers and Managements
the relation between sectors and centers is one to many and the relation between centers and Managements also one to many
I want to retrieve Json to get sector has list of centers and center has list of Managements
but I get this result

```
[{"secID":4,"cod":"400000000","name":"قطاع الأمن والخدمات المالية والإدارية","Centers":[{"ID":18,"Cent":1.0,"name":"الإدارة العامة لمكتب رئيس القطاع\"5","Mangments":[],"cod":"0401000000","SecID":4},{"ID":19,"Cent":2.0,"name":"(أ) الإدارة المركزية للخدمات الأمنية","Mangments":[],"cod":"0402000000","SecID":4},{"ID":20,"Cent":3.0,"name":"(ب)  الإدارة المركزية للخدمات الإدارية","Mangments":[],"cod":"0403000000","SecID":4},{"ID":21,"Cent":4.0,"name":"(ج) الإدارة المركزية للخدمات المالية","Mangments":[],"cod":"0404000000","SecID":4}]}
```

Mangments: []
here is my code

```
public class Sectors
{

    [Key]

    public Int32 secID { get; set; }
    
    public string cod { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Centers> Centers { get; set; }
    = new List<Centers>();

}
public class Centers
{
    [Key]

    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public double? Cent { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mangments> Mangments { get; set; }
    = new List<Mangments>();
    public string cod { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SecID")]
    //public Sectors sectors { get; set; }
    public Int32 SecID { get; set; }

}

public class Mangments
{

    [Key]

    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public string cod { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public double? mang { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CenterID")]
    //public Sectors sectors { get; set; }
    public Int32 CenterID { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the code of get method

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Sectors>>> GetSectors()
    {
        return _context.Sectors.OrderBy(c => c.name).Include(c => c.Centers).ToList();
    }
```

what can I update to get the result I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Select() method:

```
_context.Sectors.OrderBy(c => c.name)
                .Include(s => s.Centers.Select(c => c.Mangments))
                .ToList();
```

OR

You can use ThenInclude() method
https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-include-theninclude

```
_context.Sectors.OrderBy(c => c.name)
                .Include(c => c.Centers)
                   .ThenInclude(c => c.Mangments)
                .ToList();
```